# Application Wait time issue

Tags: excel

I am stuck on this bit and not sure how to get past it. I need to be able to pause and the resume my code. I went with this idea to place a value into a cell, which the Application Wait time will use.

**This bit is fine and works**

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim Response As Integer
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("Z1").Value = "01:00:00" 'will place 1hr wait time in Sheet3 Z1
t = CStr(Range("Z1"))
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(t))
```

I then have a CommandButton2 on my userform, which will reset the wait time from 1hr wait to 2 seconds. In theory this should then resume the code from where it left off. The wait time is between the **IE opening and loading** and the **FOR EACH loop running**, so once it has resumed it would action the FOR EACH loop of the code.

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("Z1").Value = "00:00:02" `Reset time to 2 sec from 1hr
```

**MY PROBLEM**

I can not click on button2 when the wait time is running. Is there a way I could do this so that when the wait time code is running, button2 is still enabled to use?

**BACKGROUND**

User click commandbutton1 and code runs, IE opens and navigates to the correct page. **NOW the code waits**. As it gives the user time to  select from several options (Too many to put in a code). Once done the user click the second command button which resets the code to 2sec and they can extract their information. In theory it should continue, however I can not click on the second button while the wait code is running. Is there a work around?

I have tried to split the code into subs, but I was having several error messages and I gave up on that method. I did look at a doEvent loop, but I am limitted in coding and was not sure how it would work and if it would **continue the code** OR **start from the begining**. *As starting from the begining is not how I want to do it.*

Thanks in advance.

**POST EDITED**
This is the code now, not 100% sure if it is correct, it now allows me to change the value of Z1 via button2 but the FOR LOOP does not run

**Before**

[image: 1hr wait time]

**After button2 is clicked**

[image: 2sec wait time]

````
'#################### APPLICATION WAIT ################
Dim i As Integer
Dim Response As Integer
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("Z1").Value = "01:00:00" 'will place the 1hr wait time in Sheet3 Z1
t = CStr(Range("Z1"))
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(t)) 'commented out or it freezes excel
WaitUntil = Now + TimeValue(t)
Do While Now <= WaitUntil
    DoEvents
Loop
'#################### APPLICATION WAIT ################

    'FOR LOOP
    For Each element In elements
      DoEvents
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.Wait()` pauses the entire application, not just your code. You should be able to achieve the intended result using a loop with `DoEvents`:

```
...
WaitUntil = Now + TimeValue(t)
Do While Now <= WaitUntil
    DoEvents
Loop
...
```

**EDIT:**
The DoEvents loop doesn't work because you set the value of `t` only once, so when your button2 changes value of `Z1` to `00:00:02`, the value of `t` is still `01:00:00`. To fix this, you can reset value of `t` inside the loop:

```
...
WaitUntil = Now + TimeValue(t)
Do While Now <= WaitUntil
    DoEvents
    If t <> CStr(Range("Z1")) Then 'If value of Z1 changed, update t
        t = CStr(Range("Z1"))
        WaitUntil = Now + TimeValue(t)
    End If
Loop
...
```

Comment: Three dumb questions the (t)  that you have added, is that refering to MY time value (t) and the value in Z1? Also, how will i resume the code? is this with the code in my button2?

Comment: @Sharid, sorry, at first I thought you were trying to pause the code only while IE is loading, not while the user is filling the form there. 
May I ask why don't you just split everything into two Subs? button1 would start your first sub and stop wheter the IE page is opened. Once the user finishes filling the form, they'll click on button2 which will run the second Sub and finish the code.

Comment: @Sharid, you said splitting into subs resulted in error messages. Can you share what you were trying to do and what were the error messages?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had added a link to a post I did on MR excel. Having looked at my original post the link is not there [https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-split-one-code-between-two-command-buttons.1130399/#post-5464656]

Comment: I have added your code, NOT SURE IF i DONE IT CORRECT. However It allowed me to change the value of z1 when button2 was clicked but the FOR EACH loop did not run. i do like this approch

Comment: @Sharid, please try the edited option. It should capture the moment when value of cell changes, wait for another 2 seconds and continue to for loop

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the problem, should anyone ever need this in the future here is the work around. Also a very big Thankyou to **Kirill Tkachenko** for putting me on the right path

I done it with a **DoWhile Loop**. This part of the code went in between browser (IE) is fully loaded and before the **FOR EACH LOOP**, then this code is triggered.

**THE CODE**

- It places a 1hr wait time in Z1, then THE DoWhile loop runs.
- When Button2 is clicked The time changes to under 3sec and the sheet recalclates
  column Z.
- Then the if statement kicks in and as the DoWhile states the time should be more 
  than 3sec and Z1 now is 2sec the GOto runs next and goes to the lable I
  created to tell the code to start here. That is just before the FOR
  EACH loop

```
'#################### APPLICATION WAIT ################
Dim i As Integer
Dim Response As Integer
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("Z1").Value = "01:00:00" 'will place the 1hr wait time in Sheet3 Z1
t = CStr(Range("Z1"))
    WaitUntil = Now + TimeValue(t)

Do While Now > "00:00:03"
Sheets("Sheet3").Columns("Z").Calculate

If Sheets("Sheet3").Range("Z1").Value = "00:00:02" Then
        GoTo StartForLoop_Restart ' use GOTo command and label to reinitiate the sub
End If
DoEvents
Loop
'#################### APPLICATION WAIT ################


'Restart the code HERE, this is the key part
StartForLoop_Restart:

    'FOR LOOP
    For Each element In elements
      DoEvents
```

This is what I put in Button2

```
 Sheets("Sheet3").Range("Z1").Value = "00:00:02"
 Sheets("Sheet3").Columns("Z").Calculate
```

I know its not the best code in the world and could be written better, but the workaround works and hopefully someone can do a much better job in writing it in the future.